# Adobe Flex code to display multiple language in the same page

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, globalization, resourcebundle

I am writing an Adobe flex (version 3.5) based application in which one of the pages should be display a combo box where it should contain different locale names in the respective languages.

For example, the combo box labels should be English (United States), 日本語 and so on.

Following is my sample code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<mx:Metadata>
    [ResourceBundle("languages")]
</mx:Metadata>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.resources.ResourceManager;

        [Bindable]
        public var items:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
            [   
                {label:ResourceManager.getInstance().getString('languages','label.english'), locale:"en_US"},
                {label:ResourceManager.getInstance().getString('languages','label.japanese'), locale:"ja_JP"},
            ]                
        );
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{items}" labelField="label"/>
</mx:Application>
```

With the above code, the combobox displays both the labels either in english or in Japanese language.

I tried ResourceManager.getInstance().localeChain api. But it modifies all the resource strings.

But I m looking at code which displays English (United States) in english language and Japanese (Japan) in Japanese language.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create the locale array collection 'items' even before application is created completely.
Try adding the logic inside creationComplete method as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    width="100%" height="100%"
    creationComplete="onCC()"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [ResourceBundle("languages")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.resources.ResourceManager;

            [Bindable]
            private var acLocales:ArrayCollection;

            private function ddlChangeHandler():void
            {
                resourceManager.localeChain = [ ddlLocale.selectedItem.locale ];
            }

            private function onCC():void
            {
                acLocales = new ArrayCollection();

                var objLocale:Object = new Object();
                objLocale.label = ResourceManager.getInstance().getString('languages', 'label.english', null, "en_US");
                objLocale.locale = "en_US";
                acLocales.addItem(objLocale);

                objLocale = new Object();
                objLocale.label = ResourceManager.getInstance().getString('languages', 'label.japanese', null, "ja_JP");
                objLocale.locale = "ja_JP";
                acLocales.addItem(objLocale);

                ddlLocale.selectedIndex = 0;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:HGroup 
        width="100%"
        horizontalAlign="center"
        verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:DropDownList id="ddlLocale"
            dataProvider="{acLocales}"
            labelField="label"
            change="ddlChangeHandler()"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Cool. I was looking this API `ResourceManager.getInstance().getString('languages', 'label.japanese', null, "ja_JP")` where we can give locale dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can write strings in your "languages" file in any language. As I understand user may choose language of application with this combobox. So, I would just create a only one "languages" file for all supported languages. For example:

languages.properties:

```
label.english=English
label.french=Français
```

Comment: How do I write Japanese language in languages.properties file ? Should I write like 日本語 ? I wanted to write Unicode character (like these \u79d2) and get that converted to japanese language while displaying in combobox ?

Comment: This is a little another question. Does you try write some words in Japanese in another .properties file. If not, I recommend you try from the simplest solution: just write "日本語".

Comment: In this tutorial used Japanese language too: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_localization_pt1.html

Comment: By Writing 日本語 in properties file or hardcoded in the code works. But my question was how can I make flex runtime to get the labels from single properties file for different locales dynamically ? Something like properties file contains `label.english=English`and `label.japanese=Japanese` and in the code `ResourceManager.getInstance().getString('languages','label.english','en_US')` to get english label in english and `ResourceManager.getInstance().getString('languages','label.japanese','ja_JP')` to read japanese label in Japanese.

Comment: By documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/resources/IResourceManager.html#getString() - the fourth argument is locale.